# CORS headers issue express Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, cors

In dev this works fine, i recently update the code in my vps and I'm getting an error in console: Acces to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.con/api/register' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I tryed with :

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});
```

and: app.use(cors()); but i'm still having the same message in console.

```js
  noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True' }) };
  
    postUser(user: User){
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/register', user, this.noAuthHeader);
  }
```

```js
    register: (req, res, next) => {
        let user = new User();
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.domain = req.body.domain;
    
        user.save((err, doc) => {
            if (!err)
                res.send(doc);
            else {
                if (err.code == 11000) {
                    if(err.keyValue.hasOwnProperty('domain')){
                        res.status(422).send(['Name repeated']);
                    }
                    if(err.keyValue.hasOwnProperty('email')){
                        res.status(422).send(['Email repeated']);
                    }               
                } else {
                    return next(err);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

The modifications i've been made in code is the verification in register() api. I'm using mongo DB and checking error code 11000 for repeated unique model data in DB (email & domain fields). Console throws CORS error when i try to register a duplicate email or domain.

EDITED:
I'm getting this error in console:

/home/myapp_full/myapp_v0.2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:19
throw error;
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.

Comment: the code seems to works fine before i update this, in adition to this i also add recaptcha to avoid bots registration

Comment: i add the changes in client too, to handle recaptcha key, and only disable submit button, but if i create a new 'no-repeated' user this works fine, the issue is when i try to sign up a registered user

Comment: no, i send token with a recaptchaService:   sendToken(token){
    return this._http.post<any>(this.url + "/recaptcha-validate", {recaptcha: token})
  } and then await validation and then send register() request to api

Comment: to be honest noAuthHeader i just copy the code snippet to make registration works

Comment: example.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: the app works fine when i register a new user, the problem is when i trying to handle a repeated user in mongoDB model by using 'unique: true'

Comment: Are www.example.com and example.com two separate servers or just two separate web addresses pointing to the same webserver?

Comment: I'm getting this error in console: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myapp.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "test@test.com" }, i dev on windows and this throws a diferent error msj, i think i find the problem, throws ''TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved: It seems that Linux and windows throws different error messages, i modified this piece of code and it's working fine, anyways the response is just 'email or name repeated' and i would like to handle each unique data, i'm still waiting for an upgrade, thanks for your time.

```js
 user.save((err, doc) => {
            if (!err)
                res.send(doc);
            else {
                if (err.code == 11000) {
                        res.status(422).send(['Email or name repeated']);
            
                } else {
                    return next(err);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should need CORS unless you actually intend to have two separate websites: `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

If, instead, your server is set up to accept requests from both, and doesn't redirect, I'd recommend that you handle redirects in your code wherever possible, so that you select one canonical URL: Either `example.com` or `www.example.com`. Barring that, as long as the script exists on both servers, just load the script without the URL (aka `"/register"`, not `this.url + "/register"`)

Answer (score -1):

One time i had the same issue with Angular and i resolved it deleting the CORS headers in the back-end. I hope that works for you.

Comment: Not sure how removing the CORS headers in your own backend would fix an error due to a lack of CORS headers

Comment: I think that it worked cause the Host that i used don't need it

Comment: clearly OP does, since the error is *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present* therefore, there's an absence of CORS headers that is causing the issue